# make list active on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I dont kknow anything about javascript help me make it active when i click on each item .
[image]

```js
$('.card > a').click(function(e){
  // find/remove all active classes from each a
  $('.mainNav > a').removeClass('active');

  // add active selected a
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card text-dark  mb-3"style="auto"  >
        <div class="card-header" style="background: #ffc221"  >  MENU </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item active"><a href="">  Math mcq</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="">  Urdu mcq</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="">  Stat mcq</a></li>
         
          
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does clicking on one of the links send you to a new page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `a` tags are not the children of your element having the `card` class, so the selector of `.card > a` is incorrect, as it only affects anchors being the children (and not descendants) of your element having the `class` of `active`. `>` means "child". Instead of that you can use space, which means descendant. Yet, it's better to target your `li` elements instead of `a` elements in order to make them active, because then you can use `siblings` out of the box in order to remove the `active` `class`. If you do not  need to remove the `active` `class` from other elements, then you can simply remove the line which calls `siblings()`.

```js
$('.card li').click(function(e){
  // find/remove all active classes from each a
  $('.mainNav > a').removeClass('active');

  // add active selected a
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass("active");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card text-dark  mb-3"style="auto"  >
        <div class="card-header" style="background: #ffc221"  >  MENU </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item active"><a href="">  Math mcq</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="">  Urdu mcq</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="">  Stat mcq</a></li>
         
          
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using jQuery? Just checking as that's what my answer will be using too.

```
$('.card > a').click(function(e){
  // find/remove all active classes from each a
  $('.mainNav > a').removeClass('active');

  // add active selected a
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

This looks fine, but I don't see `mainNav` anywhere in your question.

`>` is the direct descendent selector, so it is trying to find all `a` elements directly under `mainNav`, what I think will work better is to change the selector to something like:

```
$('ul.list-group li > a').removeClass('active');
```

Complete example:

```
$('ul.list-group li > a').click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault(); // added this line to prevent default click behaviour    

  // find/remove all active classes from each a
  $('ul.list-group li > a').removeClass('active');

  // add active selected a
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

This line might be throwing you off as well, it's hard to say without seeing the CSS, but I am guessing you *might* need to add active to the `li`, not the `a` tag itself?

If that is the case, change:

```
// add active selected a
$(this).addClass('active');
```

to

```
// add active selected li
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

If it is the `li` element that should have the active class, then this line also needs changed:

```
// find/remove all active classes from each
$('ul.list-group li').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: the script code i just copied from somewhere i dont have .mainnav enywhere in my code

Comment: that certainly won't help, I will update the answer to work with your HTML

Comment: it doesent have any css its all boot strap it's all the code i have here

Comment: I don't think bootstrap has a built in `active` class, you would need to make one or use a built in class like `bg-info`. You can try and diagnose a bit using dev tools in the browser.

Comment: can u write correct  script for my html (.active that i added myself to make it look active )

Comment: the answer should be updated now